# Change a route to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a basic app and I'm trying to destroy a record in a table called meeting_participants based on both the meeting_id and participant_id (which are columns in meeting_participants).

I have changed the destroy action in my meeting_participants_controller, to accept the meeting_id and participant_id and then delete the appropriate record.

```
def destroy
  session[:return_to] = request.referer

  @meeting_participant = MeetingParticipant.find_by_meeting_id_and_participant_id(params[:meeting_id], params[:participant_id])
  @meeting_participant.destroy

  redirect_to session[:return_to]

end
```

I have a button in a view I would like to use to call the meeting_participants#destroy controller, using the following code.

```
<table>
  <% @participants.each do |participant| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= participant.name %></dt>
        <td>
          <% participant.meetings.each do |meeting| %>
            <%= meeting.name %>
            <%= button_to( "Remove Meeting", 
                                           {:controller => "meeting_participants",
                                            :action => "destroy",
                                            :meeting_id => meeting.id,
                                            :participant_id => participant.id },
                             :method => :delete,
                             :confirm => "Are you sure?") %>
             <br/>
           <% end %>
         </td>
       </tr>
     <% end %>
  </table>
```

I think that I am successfully sending the correct participant_id and meeting_id parameters to the controller but I am getting a "No route matches" error because my route for meeting_participants#destroy is expecting a single :id parameter instead. rake routes gives...

```
meeting_participant DELETE /meeting_participants/:id(.:format)      meeting_participants#destroy
```

Does anyone know of a way to change my route to expect the two new parameters instead of id? Or maybe there is a better approach altogether. I find routes very confusing.

Thanks.

My routes.rb files is...

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :meeting_participants

  resources :participants

  resources :meetings

end
```

Comment: Can you post your routes.rb? That's where you'll need to be making the changes to the parameters in the incoming request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably create a route to handle that request. Maybe something like:

`match '/delete_meeting_participants/meeting/:meeting_id/participant/:participant_id' => 'meeting_participants#delete_meeting_participants', :as => 'delete_meeting_participants'`

Then, in your controller you would have an action called `delete_meeting_participants` that has the same logic currently in your destroy action. Obviously you would have to update your `button_to` with the name of the newly created action.

Comment: Hi Dwight, That sounds like a good solution. I've tried applying it but get an error `config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end`.

Comment: I'll look through the routes docs again because I get confused with that.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I forgot the ending single quote. I've updated my answer. That's probably what's causing it.

Comment: Dwight -- I saw that too and thought I had tried it with the extra quote. But I tried copying your text directly into routes.rb and it works great. Thank you very much for helping me -- and I'll keep reading those docs.